# Book error? Unnecessary semi-colon at function (Head First C example, Griffiths & Griffiths 2012)

Tags: c, syntax-error

It looks like this might be a typo in Head First C, 2012, Griffiths and Griffiths, published by O'Reilly. On p. 165, there's an exercise:

"There’s a new program helping the waiters bus tables at the Head First Diner. The code automatically totals a bill and adds sales tax to each item. See if you can figure out what needs to go in each of the blanks"

The error appears to be at line 7, `float add_with_tax(float f);`. The semicolon should not be here when defining a function. Am I correct on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float total = 0.0;
short count = 0;
short tax_percent = 6;

float add_with_tax(float f); // we're returning a small cash value, so it'll be a float
{
    float tax_rate = 1 + tax_percent / 100.0;
    total = total + (f * tax_rate);
    count = count + 1;
    return total;
}


int main(){
    float val;
    printf("Price of item: ");
    while (scanf("%f", &val) == 1){
        printf("Total so far: %.2f\n", add_with_tax(val));
        printf("Price of item: ");
    }
    printf("\nFinal total: %.2f\n", total);
    printf("Number of items: %hi\n", count);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The semiolon should not be there.

Comment: It's not unusual that some typos slip past editing. Many non-fiction books (especially for computer-related text books) can have an *errata* listing problems. You should also try to find a later edition where such errors might have been fixed.

Comment: Confirmed errata: http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920015482

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: .... or the semicolon you be follow by this addtion `float add_with_tax(float f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a syntax error. `float add_with_tax(float f);` is a valid prototype, so the actual error then is on the next line because you can't have a lone block `{ ... }` at file scope.